# Application crashing when adding item to listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone

When I try to add anything to a listbox, the application will just close.

This is what I have so far. The line causing it close is: `listBox1.Items.Add(term1)`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls; 
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace PhoneApp1 {
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    // Constructor
    public class Item {
        public string itemLine1 { get; set; }
        public string itemLine2 { get; set; }
    }

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.itemLine1 = "Item11";
        item.itemLine2 = "Item12";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.itemLine1 = "Item21";
        item.itemLine2 = "Item22";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.itemLine1 = "Item31";
        item.itemLine2 = "Item32";
        list.Add(item);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        listBox1.ItemsSource = list
        ));

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler (wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.usi.edu/webservices/iphone/USIINFOterms.xml"));

    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
        ApplicationTitle.Text = e.Result;            
        string terms = ApplicationTitle.Text;
        ApplicationTitle.Text = "Course Catalog";
        string term1 = terms.Substring(terms.IndexOf("value"+7),terms.IndexOf("/value"));
        listBox1.Items.Add(term1);
    }

    private void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (sender != null) PageTitle.Text = sender.ToString();
        if (e != null) PageTitle.Text = e.AddedItems.Count.ToString();

        IEnumerator ie = e.AddedItems.GetEnumerator();
        ie.MoveNext();

        if (e != null) ApplicationTitle.Text = ie.Current.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is in the output window of Visual Studio when this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You've set the ItemsSource to accept a type of Item, but then you're adding a string to it. Turn the string into an Item before adding it, so that it matches the expected type of the ItemSource.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a string to a list of items.  My guess is that you're getting an InvalidTypeException or similar.  Instead of `listBox1.Items.Add(term1)`, try creating a new item and assigning `term1` to `item.itemLine1`, then `listBox1.Items.Add(item)`.